# Use MAX only on rows which match ON criteria

Tags: mysql, join

How can I modify the following query to restrict the addition from `choice` to only one row per `nid`, the one with the highest value in the field `foo`?  That is, there are multiple rows in the `choice` table with the same `nid`, and I want the highest `foo` of each `nid` to be joined to `node`.

```
SELECT *
FROM `node`
LEFT JOIN `choice` ON node.nid = choice.nid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM node
  LEFT JOIN choice c USING (nid)
 WHERE (c.nid, c.foo) IN (SELECT nid, max(foo) FROM choice GROUP BY nid);
```

[Try it out on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0f1d/1).

---

**EDIT:**

Speaking bout adding `bar` into the list.

In the subquery I'm finding `MAX(foo)` for each `nid`, therefore `GROUP BY nid`. There's no logic in adding `bar` as it is, you should either use an aggregate on that column or include it into the `GROUP BY`. It is MySQL “extension” (*which I personally find error prone*), that allows you to make such things. I assume, that MySQL does `MAX(bar)` behind the scenes.
If you'll run query:

```
mysql> SELECT nid, max(foo), max(bar) FROM choice GROUP BY nid;
+------+----------+------+
| nid  | max(foo) | bar  |
+------+----------+------+
|    1 |        3 | Uno  |
|    2 |        1 | Eins |
+------+----------+------+
```

you'll see, that `MAX(foo)` and `MAX(bar)` are taken from different rows.
Compare the output with the following:

```
SELECT nid, max(foo), bar FROM choice GROUP BY nid;
```

As soon as `nid` + `foo` combination is unique within `choice` I would recommend *not* to add more values into the subquery. Otherwise the overall approach needs to be changed.

Comment: +1 I was close to your solution in my research.  I like that yours uses `MAX()`.  Great link!
I'm not sure how `(c.nid, c.foo)` works in your `WHERE` clause.  While trying to find out, I was surprised to get only 1 result when I added c.bar to the mix. (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ad83/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this very efficiently with a join like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM node
LEFT JOIN choice c1
  ON c1.nid = node.nid
LEFT JOIN choice c2
  ON c2.nid = node.nid
  AND c2.foo > c1.foo
WHERE c2.foo IS NULL
```

The one draw back to this method is that if you have records with duplicate foo, you will get duplicate records.